# Difference between “verpassen” and “verfehlen”?

Tags: meaning, difference

I am having trouble understanding what is the difference between *verpassen* and *verfehlen.*

Comment: Typically, *verpassen* is missing something in time (by being too late), and *verfehlen* is missing something in space (by aiming to high, too low, too short, etc.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both *etw. verpassen* and *etw. verfehlen* translate to English *miss sth*. However, they are used in different contexts:

> einen Zug/Bus etc. verpassen

= miss a train/bus etc.

> ein Ziel verfehlen

= miss a goal/target

*Verpassen* can also be used with people, (*jmd. verpassen*). It also translates to *miss sb.* but only in the sense of "failing to reach sb." and not in a sense of feeling the absence of sb, which in German is *jmd. vermissen*.

Comment: As a hint, *verpassen* literally means people/things passed each other without touching (or even seeing), while *verfehlen* focuses on *der Fehler* done by missing a set goal.

Comment: @Janka Well, if you shoot an arrow and miss the target people would say *Ich habe die Zielscheibe verfehlt*, although *verpasst* would be okay, too, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hi sorry if i am also to venture into a grammar question, but why is  "Ich habe die Zielscheibe verfehlt" and not " Ich habe die Zielscheibe verfehlen" ?

Comment: Because *Ich* is 1st person singular, which requires to conjugate the verb accordingly, while *verfehlen* is the infinitive. But you should ask another question for that.

Answer (score 6):

The two words, verpassen and verfehlen, both mean to "miss." But in slightly different ways.

"Verpassen" is to let something "pass" or get by, that you should have been able to get. One would use this to refer to a missed meeting with a person, or a deadline for a task, or a timetable for a train or bus.

"Verfehlen" has more of the connotation of failing to achieve something that was relatively uncertain to begin with. One might "verfehlen" to get a promotion, for instance.

Comment: Can it be roughly said that verpassen is used for *tangible missed things*, while verfehlen is for *intangibles*?

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Not quite. I would think in turns of "elusiveness" rather than "tangibility." They are similar, but not the same. Example from adjan's answer: "Verpassen can also be used with people, (jmd. verpassen). It also translates to miss sb. but only in the sense of "failing to reach sb." and not in a sense of feeling the absence of sb,"

Comment: That means even if there is no sharp distinction between these verbs, it is possible to differentiate by considering "elusiveness". I got the point thanks for your great comment + answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here a collection of good phrases using *verpassen* and *verfehlen*.

Note that typically you cannot interchange *verpassen* and *verfehlen* in these phrases.

**Verpassen:**

> eine Gelegenheit verpassen
>
> eine Theatervorstellung verpassen
>
> den richtigen Moment verpassen
>
> den Zug/Bus/Flug verpassen, die Straßenbahn/Fähre verpassen
>
> den Freund verpassen (während man auf ihn wartet, um ihn zu überraschen)
>
> den Sonnenuntergang verpassen

As we see, all this seems to be related to time.

**Verfehlen:**

> ein Ziel verfehlen
>
> das Klassenziel verfehlen [typical expression used by teachers for students who will have to repeat a year at school due to insufficient learning results]
>
> der Fußballer hat das Tor verfehlt
>
> den rechten Ton verfehlen
>
> den Treffpunkt verfehlen
>
> das rechte Maß verfehlen

One could argue that this tends to be related to place/space, although *Maß* and *Ton* need some mental gymnastics to be seen in a place/space perspective.

Notably however

> den rechten Augenblick verfehlen

sounds correct to me, although it would contradict the rule of time/space association.